# how can I load the waypoint coordinates from Asp Label.Text

Tags: javascript, asp.net, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

First code in which i hardcore the value:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {
    var label3LatLng = 
document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
      var label4LatLng = 
document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value;
      
       
      L.Routing.control({
          waypoints: [
          L.latLng(21.5278654, 55.9196996), 
          L.latLng(23.5278654, 55.9196996) 

          ],
          routeWhileDragging: true,
          geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()
       
      }).addTo(map);
    }
```

Output:[![Output with hardcore][1]][1]

Code with textbox or labels:
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

```
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>         
         
         
             <input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="Click Me" 
style="width:300px;">
            
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="d1"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction() {
    var label3LatLng = 
document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
      var label4LatLng = 
document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value;
      
       
      L.Routing.control({
          waypoints: [
          L.latLng(label3LatLng.trim()), // This assumes the label contains both latitude & longitude.
          L.latLng(label4LatLng.trim()) // Note: call trim to remove any potential whitespace.

          ],
          routeWhileDragging: true,
          geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim()
       
      }).addTo(map);
    }
```

[![Output when entered with TextBox][2]][2]

Even if i enter the values in the Textbox Alert message shows the value but routing machine shows empty values.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x85v2.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MzyC.png

Comment: Please can you add HTML (which includes label & textbox) to this question?

Comment: That's a lot better, for future reference you should include the code as html (instead of screenshot as it allows to be re-creatable locally). What does alert(label3LatLng) display? Also if you were to replace L.latLng(label3LatLng) with  a hardcoded value, does the map display crrectly?

Comment: Alert meassge shows the value of textbox plus when I hardcore the values in L.LatLng(label3LatLng) it works 100% fine and it creates a route which is shown in map

Comment: It feels like the alert message is showing different data to what you're using as hardcoded value (perhaps 1 is a string and the other is a number). However without being able to see the output, it will be difficult to debug. Is there any chance you can add the output to the question?